# How to get list of installed features in Karaf using REST API?

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

I know using command line it can be get by running `feature:list -i` but is there any API/JSON available to fetch this?

Comment: Hi Apul, did you find the way? I also interested in this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jolokia and hawtio to retrieve that information. Quite easily. I believe you can easily add the hawtio repo from the native karaf repos in features (repo-add hawtio). Then you need to install jolokio, hawtio, and the karaf web console. From the karaf webconsole alone you can see a full list of features, but I find the hawtio interface to be a god send.

Answer (score 0):

A REST API can be installed without the need for Hawtio, which uses [jolokia](https://jolokia.org/) for accessing the bundle list under the hood.
The jolokia project provides web applications called *agents* serving a REST API. For quick experiments you can deploy the war [jolokia-war-unsecured](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jolokia/jolokia-war-unsecured/1.6.0/) into the hot deploy folder of a running karaf instance. This installs a A REST web service at e.g. `http://localhost/jolokia-war-unsecured/` which does not require any authentications.